# how to insert a row into a tbody specific column by javascript in ie

Tags: internet-explorer, html-tbody

What I need to know is how to insert a row into a tbody with specific column,for example I need to insert after the second  row .
I know I can do it with jquery ,but it does not suit in IE

I have tried it with jquery but I got an error '"对象不支持“after”属性或方法"'

```
var tr1 = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr')[1];
var newRow = tbody.insertRow()
tr1.after(newRow)
```

I expect I can get a row after the second row .

Comment: Show your attempt with jquery and translate this error to english

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer .

```
tbody.insertRow(2)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22234401)

Comment: When I  asked this question ，I do not know the answer。But  a soon later  I found the answer in w3cschool.

Comment: I can see that you had posted the solution for your above question. I suggest you to mark your own answer as an accepted answer after 24 hrs, when it is available to mark it. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.